# pass value to generic to get type typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a function

```js
function getExtendedObject<T extends object>( currentObject: T ) {
  return {
    ...currentObject,
    newProp: "value1",
    anotherProp: () => "something"
  }
}
```

i need to get the return type of this function for a specific input.

```js
type example = ReturnType<typeof getExtendedObject>
```

the above will give me

```js
type example = object & {
    newProp: string;
    anotherProp: number;
}
```

but instead of object, i want a specific value. something like,

```js
type example = { name: "john", marks: 91 } & {
    newProp: string;
    anotherProp: number;
}
```

how can i achieve this

Comment: You can't do what you want since `getExtendedObject` doesn't know what T is until it's called. If you have an instance of a variable you could do that.

Like: `const foo = getExtendedObject({ name: 'john', marks: 91 }); type example = typeof foo`

Comment: This is possible in the future very soon when 4.7 is released with instantiation expressions.